# Way of setting of onClickListener()

Tags: java, android, for-loop, onclick, this

I created a ImageView object(img) and pass some resources through the same object(img) to a Linear Layout with a *for-loop*. On each Iteration of the loop I invoke a setOnClickListener() on *img*(`img.setOnClickListener()`) to show a Toast that reflects the value of the loop controller variable (*i*). The code segment i tried is below:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) 
              {

    img = new ImageView(this);

    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.thambu);

    body.addView(img);



    this.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


    Toast.makeText(Details.this, Integer.toString(i) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });

        }
```

The thing is whenever i click on the Images that is generated, i have a Toast displaying 7.

I know why its displaying 7. but i want to display the index of the image that is being clicked.

(*body* is the id of a linear layout on which i pass an ImageView)

How can i do that on android. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) 
              {

    img = new ImageView(this);

    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.thambu);

    body.addView(img);
    img.setTag(i);



    this.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        int tagInt = (int) v.getTag();

    Toast.makeText(Details.this, Integer.toString(tagInt) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });

        }
```

try this, i have used tags..

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's rather a general Java question.

You should do something like the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {

  img = new ImageView(this);

  img.setImageResource(R.drawable.thambu);

  body.addView(img);


  final int j = i;
  this.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(Details.this, Integer.toString(j) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  });
}
```